# Populate based on choice values in select field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I am new to react and had a design challenge to overcome. What I want to do is have a set of choice values in the choice field. Each choice value will have different set of KPIs and UOMs . Based on the choice value I selected I should be able to use pop up to select different KPI values. Once I select a set of KPI values. I should be able to display that in the table below.

Can anybody show me an example of how to do this? I am using material ui and react-bootstrap for the same

Here is the picture of that below

[image]

Comment: The choices are multiple choice

Comment: This is a bit vague. Are you trying to pass the data from the pop-up window back to the main application?

Comment: Originally it uses a db for the same, but what I want to do is have a set of values for the process choices and based on the process choice populate the KPI pop up

Comment: If I am understanding your problem correctly it seems like you should be setting state based on user selections and then use that data when you display the pop-up.

Comment: Yes , Do you have an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example:

```
function Page(props) {

    const [choice1, setChoice1] = React.useState(null)
    const [choice2, setChoice2] = React.useState(null)
    ... as many as you need
 
    const handleChoice1 = (event) => {
        setChoice1(event.target.value)
    }
    ... as many as you need
 
    return (
        <div>
            Your page here with selections that call your handleChoice functions when users select them
        </div>
        <Popup open={open}>
            <DisplayContent choice1={choice1} choice2={choice2} />
        </Popup>
        
    )
 
 }
```

Pass your state to `<DisplayContent />` and render the correct data accordingly. Render nothing if they are null.

My example is overly simplistic since I don't know how you are implementing anything.